# How to cast local files with React Native

Tags: react-native, google-cast, google-cast-sdk, react-native-google-cast

I am working on an app that cast local files to chromecast devices using react-native-google-cast but as the google cast library only supports http so how can I host my local files on a local server in my react native project. I have came across [tinydroidhttpd](https://github.com/dddge/TinyDroidHttpd)
but I have no idea how to use it in my project.
Please help me out.